# Call php on webserver from python

Tags: php, python

I have a php script on my webserver. When I call ..../myscript.php in the webserver, the script writes something into a file.
How can I call this script from a python program, running on my computer...
I tried different things request, subprocess etc. - nothing worked.
Whatwould be the right way to do this?

Regards

Adriana

Answer (score 2):

You have lot of methods to do this. One of them is using request:

```
import requests

url = "http://domain.name/script.php"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Or using urllib

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen("http://domain.name/script.php")
data = response.read()
```

Comment: Thank you- I tried these. But the script isn't executed (the script in the script.php- when I call script.php from browser, it works)

Comment: Its impossible :) Maybe you need check your firewall? I think that Python haven't access to internet for some reason.